# Unable to run flutter project. Asking for specific NDK version

Tags: android, flutter, dart, android-ndk

Launching lib\main.dart on M2004J19C in debug mode...

- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred configuring project ':flutter_libserialport'.

> NDK at C:\Users\M.K. Malik\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\ndk\21.1.6352462 did not have a source.properties file

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 2m 47s
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...                            175.8s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

How to fix or install that specific NDK version?

Answer (score 1):

You need to download `NDK` from `SDK Manager` in `SDK Tools` Tab (select show package details)

In Some Cases, `CMake` also needed which is also available in `SDK Tools` tab

And in app/build.gradle file you need to specify the version

like this
`ndkVersion "25.1.8937393"`

Answer (score 0):

Firstly check your NDK version using android studio

Go to Tools->SDK Manager (or Files->Settings->Appearance & Behavior->System Settings->Android SDK ). Then select the SDK Tools tab, and check the Show Package Details checkbox. You will see your NDK version.

You can also easily install or upgrade new NDK version using android studio -> SDK manager -> SDK tools . Select the show package detail checkbox. You will be able to see all the NDK versions available.

The error displayed by you shows that some file in missing from the NDK version you have my suggestion is you should reinstall that version